# Could not open input file: drush

Tags: drush, installation

I have a relatively fresh instance of Ubuntu 16.04 running a Drupal 7 site, with php5.6 installed instead of php7.  The drupal site runs well.  I am trying to get drush installed so that I can easily do updates.

I have done the global install per http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/

Specifically, as the ubuntu user (no root login)

wget http://files.drush.org/drush.phar

/usr/bin/php5.6 drush.phar core-status

PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini 
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush script           :  /home/ubuntu/drush.phar
 Drush version          :  8.1.12
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :

chmod +x drush.phar

sudo mv drush.phar /usr/bin/drush

/usr/bin/php5.6 drush --version

Could not open input file: drush

What am I missing?

Comment: What does `which drush` output? If it outputs /usr/bin/drush, then check drush is readable.

Comment: $ which drush
/usr/bin/drush

Comment: Drush is standalone, just use `drush --version`

Comment: Thanks.  That leads me back to an earlier problem.  When I try to use it without specifying a php version, I get an error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cache_get() in /home/crm/domains/testing.crm.botany.org/public_html/includes/module.inc:754
I googled this, and found references to this being a problem when running under php7.  Thus, I was trying to force it to use the 5.6 binary.

Other solutions for this problem included drush not finding the settings.php file (I am in the right directory and the file permissions are OK), and specifying 127.0.0.1 for host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found to fix this problem is to change the default php used by the server. In other words, /usr/bin/php was originally a symlink to /usr/bin/php7.1, and changing it to a symlink to /usr/bin/php5.6 solved the problem.

But it appears that drush will always use the default php even if you install it with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting when you run `/usr/bin/php5.6 drush --version` is because you are telling /usr/bin/php5.6 to execute the *drush* file present in the current directory, but since you moved it to /usr/bin, it cannot find it. PHP doesn't look for the file in the PATH.

To use a specific PHP version to run Drush you need:

- Set the *DRUSH_PHP* environment variable to the filename of the PHP executable

  - bash

    ```
    DRUSH_PHP="/usr/bin/php5.6" drush --version
    ```
  - Other shells (e.g. fish, tcsh)

    ```
    env DRUSH_PHP="/usr/bin/php5.6" drush --version
    ```
- Tell PHP where to find the drush file

  ```
  /usr/bin/php5.6 /usr/bin/drush --version
  ```

Basing on a comment given for [Modifying the PHP or PHP configuration that drush runs under](https://www.drupal.org/node/1302418), it seems the most recent versions of Drush don't use the *DRUSH_PHP* variable anymore.